# How to call an activity only after a different activity has completed?

Tags: android

I have an Android project where I have an Activity that downloads a .APK file.  After the download is complete I need to fire another Activity that installs it.

How can I make the Install Activity fire only after the Download Activity is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download, and fire the new activity in `onPostExecute()`

Answer (score 1):

While MByD is probably in correct in that you probably want to use AsyncTask for downloading, to answer your question directly, you would use a parent activity and call your downloading activity with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) and then set [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to start the next activity when returning with some value (eg. `public final static int ON_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE = 1`).

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution but it doesn't appear to be able to detect when the file is downloaded before onActivityResult is called.

Comment: It wouldn't.  Your child activity would start the download and wait for it to complete before exiting.  When it exits, it would tell the parent activity, basically alerting it that the download is complete.  When onActivityResult is called, that's when you would know the download is complete.

In terms of both simplicity and performance/usability, AsyncTask is actually the better approach.